# WebGL not working neither in Firefox nor Chrome

Tags: nvidia, firefox, google-chrome, opengl, webgl

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 and finally managed to install the correct drivers for my nVidia card (using bumblebee) and glxinfo finally shows that I support OpenGL 4.20. So, lastly, for the project I'm working on, I need to get WebGL running in either Chrome or Firefox (I'd rather use in Chrome) to test the program I'm developing. I believe this may be a conflict with my on-board Intel HD5000 maybe?

When I try to run the WebGL .html file in Firefox I get this in the terminal:

```
(process:8315): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
    OpenGL Warning: glFlushVertexArrayRangeNV not found in mesa table
    OpenGL Warning: glVertexArrayRangeNV not found in mesa table
    OpenGL Warning: glCombinerInputNV not found in mesa table
    OpenGL Warning: glCombinerOutputNV not found in mesa table
    OpenGL Warning: glCombinerParameterfNV not found in mesa table
    OpenGL Warning: glCombinerParameterfvNV not found in mesa table
    OpenGL Warning: glCombinerParameteriNV not found in mesa table
    OpenGL Warning: glCombinerParameterivNV not found in mesa table
    OpenGL Warning: glFinalCombinerInputNV not found in mesa table
    OpenGL Warning: glGetCombinerInputParameterfvNV not found in mesa table
    OpenGL Warning: glGetCombinerInputParameterivNV not found in mesa table
    OpenGL Warning: glGetCombinerOutputParameterfvNV not found in mesa table
    OpenGL Warning: glGetCombinerOutputParameterivNV not found in mesa table
    OpenGL Warning: glGetFinalCombinerInputParameterfvNV not found in mesa table
    OpenGL Warning: glGetFinalCombinerInputParameterivNV not found in mesa table
    OpenGL Warning: glDeleteFencesNV not found in mesa table
    OpenGL Warning: glFinishFenceNV not found in mesa table
    OpenGL Warning: glGenFencesNV not found in mesa table
    OpenGL Warning: glGetFenceivNV not found in mesa table
    OpenGL Warning: glIsFenceNV not found in mesa table
    OpenGL Warning: glSetFenceNV not found in mesa table
    OpenGL Warning: glTestFenceNV not found in mesa table
    ATTENTION: default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment.
    OpenGL Warning: Unimplemented glxMakeCurrent call with GLXPixmap passed, unexpected things might happen.
    OpenGL Warning: Failed to get windows geometry for 0x7ff7e0b8d800, try xwininfo
    OpenGL version detected: 210
    OpenGL Warning: Unknown program 0
    OpenGL version detected: 210
    OpenGL Warning: Unknown program 0
    OpenGL version detected: 210
    OpenGL Warning: Unknown program 0
    OpenGL Warning: Unimplemented glxMakeCurrent call with GLXPixmap passed, unexpected things might happen.
    OpenGL Warning: Failed to get windows geometry for 0x7ff7d14b3800, try xwininfo
    OpenGL version detected: 210
    OpenGL Warning: Unknown program 0
    OpenGL Warning: Unimplemented glxMakeCurrent call with GLXPixmap passed, unexpected things might happen.
    OpenGL Warning: Failed to get windows geometry for 0x7ff7d14b3800, try xwininfo
    OpenGL version detected: 210
    OpenGL Warning: Unknown program 0
```

And in Chrome I get the following:

```
OpenGL Warning: glFlushVertexArrayRangeNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glVertexArrayRangeNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glCombinerInputNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glCombinerOutputNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glCombinerParameterfNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glCombinerParameterfvNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glCombinerParameteriNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glCombinerParameterivNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glFinalCombinerInputNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetCombinerInputParameterfvNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetCombinerInputParameterivNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetCombinerOutputParameterfvNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetCombinerOutputParameterivNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetFinalCombinerInputParameterfvNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetFinalCombinerInputParameterivNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glDeleteFencesNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glFinishFenceNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGenFencesNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetFenceivNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glIsFenceNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glSetFenceNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glTestFenceNV not found in mesa table
ATTENTION: default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment.
OpenGL Warning: glXChooseFBConfig returning NULL, due to attrib=0x2, next=0x20
[8501:8501:0119/161214:ERROR:gl_surface_glx.cc(739)] glXChooseFBConfig failed.
[8501:8501:0119/161214:ERROR:gpu_info_collector.cc(27)] gfx::GLContext::CreateOffscreenGLSurface failed
[8501:8501:0119/161214:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(142)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process
OpenGL Warning: glXChooseFBConfig returning NULL, due to attrib=0x2, next=0x20
[8501:8501:0119/161214:ERROR:gl_surface_glx.cc(739)] glXChooseFBConfig failed.
[7:7:0119/161214:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(164)] Failed to initialize command buffer service.
OpenGL Warning: glXChooseFBConfig returning NULL, due to attrib=0x2, next=0x20
[8501:8501:0119/161214:ERROR:gl_surface_glx.cc(739)] glXChooseFBConfig failed.
[7:7:0119/161214:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(164)] Failed to initialize command buffer service.
```

My nVidia card is a 765GTXM. When I run the exact same file in Windows everything runs smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar problems with Chromium (and Chrome when I downloaded that).  It turns out that WebGL is still classed as experimental, and so it's switched off by default for us.

To turn it on enter the following address into the address bar:

```
chrome://flags
```

and press enter (or refresh).

Then select the 'Enable' link under
**Override software rendering list**

You have to then close down Chrome (or Chromium) in order for the changes to take effect.

Sorted.  =)